# UrlRewriteFilter: www and https redirect

Tags: url-rewriting, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I am using Tuckey UrlRewriteFilter to force users to go to the 'www' and 'https' version of my web. I mean next 3 URLs must redirect to `https://www.myweb.com`

- `http://www.myweb.com`
- `http://myweb.com`
- `https://myweb.com`

The problem comes with the last one, I cannot find the solution to put 'www' for 'https'. I have the next rule that makes 2 first cases work without problems:

```
  <rule>
    <name>Domain Name Check</name>
    <condition name="host" operator="equal">myweb.com$</condition>
    <condition type="scheme" operator="equal">^http$</condition>
    <from>^(.*)$</from>
    <to type="permanent-redirect">https://www.myweb.com$1</to>
  </rule>
```

This one of course does not apply for the third case. If I try a similar rule for the third case like the following, it doesn't work either (I don't know why):

```
  <rule>
    <name>Domain Name Check</name>
    <condition name="host" operator="equal">myweb.com$</condition>
    <condition type="scheme" operator="equal">^https$</condition>
    <from>^(.*)$</from>
    <to type="permanent-redirect">https://www.myweb.com$1</to>
  </rule>
```

Could you please help me to figure out the rule for the third case?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was not the filter but my certificate. I issued my certificate for `www.myweb.com` but not for `myweb.com` so `https://myweb.com` request didn't reach my server, the browser detected the certificate was not valid and blocked the process.

I just issued my certificate for `https://myweb.com` and modified my Tuckey rule as you can see below. Now `https://www.myweb.com` is the only URL users can use.

```
  <rule> 
    <name>Domain Name Check</name>
    <condition type="request-url" operator="equal">(^http://myweb.com|^http://www.myweb.com|^https://myweb.com)</condition>
    <from>^(.*)$</from>
    <to type="redirect">https://www.myweb.com$1</to>
  </rule>
```